# Select no carga primer dato

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, select

Tengo el código de un `select` dependiente, al seleccionar algún dato (idiomas), carga los datos en un nuevo `select` (horarios). Pero no funciona totalmente, el primer dato de la lista no lo toma, a partir del segundo dato funciona bien. Como podrán observar, la lista 2 la toma de una base de datos `mysql`.

Me podrían ayudar a detectar el error? Espero me haga entender. Gracias.

Este es el formulario:

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Agregar fila de campos DINAMICOS</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".soc").change(function(){
          var tr =  $(this).parent().parent();
         //alert($('.idi').val());
          idi = $(this).val();
          $.post("getIdiomas.php", { idi: idi }, 
          function(data){
            tr.find("#term").html(data); 
          });
        })

        $("#adicional").on('click', function(){
          var row = $("#tabla tbody tr:eq(0)").clone(true).removeClass('fila-fija');
          row.find('.term').empty(); 
          row.appendTo("#tabla tbody")
        });

        $(".eliminar").on("click",function(){
          var parent = $(this).closest("tr").remove();
        });
      }); 
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <table align="center" class="table bg-info" id="tabla">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>IDIOMAS</th>
             <th>HORARIOS</th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr class="fila-fija">
             <td>
                <select class="idi" name="idi[]">
                   <option value="NULL">Seleccionar</option>
                   <option value="1">ingles</option>
                   <option value="2">frances</option>
                   <option value="3">portugues</option>
                </select>
             </td>
             <td><select name="term[]" class="term" id="term"></select></td>
             <td class="eliminar"><input type="button" value="-"/></td>
          </tr>
       </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="btn-der"><button id="adicional" name="adicional" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">+</button></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Este es el archivo del segundo select (archivo getIdiomas.php):

```html
<?php 
    include('conexion.php'); 
    $idi = $_POST['idi']; 
    $query="SELECT cod_hor,horario from horario where cod_hor='$idi'";  
    $result=$mysqli->query($query); 
    $html = "<option value=''>Seleccionar</option>"; 
      
    while (($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) != NULL) { 
        $html.= "<option value='".$fila['cod_hor']."'>".$fila['horario']." </option>"; 
    } 
    echo $html 
?>
```

Comment: si te das cuenta el primer dato es `NULL` por eso no toma ningun idioma!

Comment: A que te refieres con _"el primer dato de la lista no lo toma"_? de cual de los 2 `select` estas hablando, `idiomas u horarios`? Que es lo que esperas que suceda cuando seleccionas el primero dato? **Importante** [Tu código es susceptible a Inyección SQL](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/18232/16597)

Comment: a esto me refiero `<select class="idi" name="idi[]">
                     <option value="NULL">Seleccionar</option>` envias NULL por eso no te retorna nada :V

Comment: Revisaré tu comentarios Bryro,  muchas gracias. Ya comentaré.

Comment: Lo que puedes hacer es vaciar la segunda lista cuando el valor de la primera sea null

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario Marcos, la lista idiomas debe cargar los datos de horarios, cuando selecciono el primer dato, debe cargar los horarios correspondientes al idioma 1 (inglés). Si selecciono idioma 2 (francés), que funciona bien, se muestran los horarios correspondientes a ese idioma. Espero quede más claro. Gracias.

Comment: @AndrésVillamarín, se me ocurre que el problema puede estar en la consulta de horarios. Aquí: `$query="SELECT cod_hor,horario from horario where cod_hor='$idi'";`, diría que **`where cod_hor='$idi'` esta mal**, ya que `cod_hor` debe ser un **identificador** del `horario` y no del `idioma`. Se me hace que la consulta debería ser algo así `$query="SELECT cod_hor,horario from horario where cod_idi='$idi'";`, donde `cod_idi` es la columna que determina el **idioma** al que pertenece el **horario**

Comment: Gracias a todos por sus opiniones y comentarios y si @Marcos, tenias razón, cómo no lo pude mirar antes, y le dí muchísimas vueltas y nunca encontré la solución... Pero al fin funcionó. De nuevo, mil gracias, son unos duros, mis respetos.

Comment: @AndrésVillamarín, me alegro haber sido de ayuda. Considera borrar la pregunta si el problema era ese. Saludos!

Comment: @Marcos ¿por qué no escribes una respuesta basada en consultas preparadas? Podría ser viable, creo yo, para este caso. Saludos.

Comment: Personalmente creo que no amerita una respuesta dado que el problema se debe a un error en la condición aplicada en la consulta (uso de columna erronea)

Comment: @Marcos, Buen día de nuevo, tengo ahora otra duda, como haría para contar el número de filas que la tabla va creando? Me podrías ayudar? Gracias.

Comment: @AndrésVillamarín Te recomiendo que crees una nueva pregunta donde detalles lo que buscas y el problema que tienes